# Where does directline store files which are uploaded through directline upload api?

Tags: botframework, bots, chatbot, direct-line-botframework

I am developing a chatbot for a client where I am using directline upload API.
So I am getting a temporary link of the attachment (like this link "https://directline.botframework.com/attachments/GUytYCxY7eZ8JGFEuggYyJ-j/0000002/0/72944804-56a6fa333df78cf772913cd3.jpg?t=xxxxtoken"), and directline doc says that it is valid for 24 hours. So where does Directline store these uploaded files? Is there any limit to the upload storage that directline is using.

Answer (score 0):

Attachments for Direct Line are stored encrypted on Microsoft servers. The size limit currently is 20MB and the contents will be available for 24 hours.